# Pattern match middle of list in Elixir

Tags: pattern-matching, elixir

Is there a way to pattern match something like [_head | middle | _last] in Elixir? That is, I want to match on a list that has at least three things in it (but often more), but only match on everything but the head and last element.

Example:

```
    def match_middle([_head | middle | _last]) do
      IO.inspect middle
    end

    match_middle [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    >>> [2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Probably there is no way

Comment: Are you sure you want to pattern match and not just extract the list without the first and last elements?

Comment: @GavinBrelstaff I was wondering specifically about pattern matching, but if you have a succinct way of doing it, I'd like to see it. I am currently using the first thing that came to mind. I don't see a way to format code in comments.... Here it is with semi-colons to guide the way.
    [_ | rest] = items;
    [_last | rest_backwards] = Enum.reverse rest;
    middle = Enum.reverse(rest_backwards)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you might see, [`List.pop_at/3`](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/master/lib/elixir/lib/list.ex#L921) is itself implemented using recursion, `:lists.reverse`, and head access. That said, there is no way to directly access the last element in the list.

On the other hand, if you are concern, that there can’t be more than, say, `N` elements in the list, the direct pattern match is still achievable:

```
defmodule MatchInTheMiddle do
  @n 10
  Enum.each(0..@n, fn i ->
    @match_clause Enum.map(0..i, fn j -> {:"p#{j}", [], Elixir} end)
    def match_middle(unquote(
      [{:_head, [], Elixir}] ++ @match_clause ++ [{:_last, [], Elixir}])
    ), do: IO.inspect unquote(@match_clause)
  end)
end
```

And, yes, the graceful fallback for short and long lists:

```
def match_middle([]), do: []
def match_middle([_]), do: []
def match_middle([_head | tail]) do
  with [_tail | middle] <- :lists.reverse(tail), do: middle
end

MatchInTheMiddle.match_middle([1,2,3,4])
#⇒ [2,3]
```

This is not as elegant as you probably expected it to be, but in some cases it might be helpful, since these clauses are *compiled* into pattern matches and on huge amounts of data this is rather more efficient that `Enum` operations.

Comment: This is the closest to being an expression I could use in a guard or as a pattern match. Indeed, not super elegant though.

Answer (score 5):

Elixir lists are really cons lists that go way back into the early days of Lisp.

```
iex(1)> foo = [1 ,2 , 3]
[1, 2, 3]
iex(2)> [ head | [ middle | tail ]] = foo
[1, 2, 3]
iex(3)> middle
2
```

So while we write it as `[1,2,3]` it is really `[1, [2,[3,[]]]]`

However, that really doesn't cover what you are asking. Something like this maybe

```
def match_middle([_head | [ second | tail]]) when tail != [] do
  flip_tail = Enum.reverse(tail)
  [end | rest] = flip_tail
  [second | Enum.reverse(rest) ]
end
```

Comment: Honestly, this is not a “_pattern match_ something like `[_head | middle | _last]`,” e. g. it can’t be used in guard.

Answer (score 3):

Propably I would solve that without pattern matching, because your case is quite specific - you assume that `middle` is everything except first and last elements, but split operator works in different manner - it splits list for first element and everything else as `tail`.

In your case I would create private function for matching the middle:

```
defp get_middle_from_list(list) do
  list 
  |> Stream.drop(1)
  |> Stream.drop(-1)
  |> Enum.to_list()
end
```

and use it

```
get_middle_from_list [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
> [2, 3, 4]
```

Of course it will return `[]` if list contain less then 3 elements.